# Ankhsvn not integrated to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I have a website project that has been subversioned already. I have installed ankhsvn but when I open the website project in Visual Studio 2010 it doesn't show the version control icons in the Solution Explorer. Any idea why that might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Did you enable AnkhSVN in Tools->Options->Source Control?

When it is the default SCC provider it should automatically detect that your (C# ?) website project is already in Subversion.

Comment: for me it was enabled by default in VS2008. I expected the same thing for VS2010 but it didn't happen. :) Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue. I just opened a project from codeplex with source control pointed at a TFS server and it detached my SVN projects from source control.

Comment: It enabled by default in vs2010 but not in vs2012. You answer saved my time.Thank you

Comment: Don't forget check "Show all settings" in the ShowDialog.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Express Versions of Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012, note that AnkhSVN does not work with Express versions. In my case (VS 2012) the solution above does not work because AnkhSVN is not available in Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plugin Selection. Express versions do not allow Addin.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12509780

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but after installing Ankh I had to run

> "d:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup

to get Ankh to show up in the source control plugin selection list. This seems to happen intermittently with new plugins.

Comment: The AnkhSVN setup performs this step for you. If you see this fail often most likely you have some Visual Studio plugin/extension with serious problems. With this flags all VS plugins are loaded to allow them to complete their setup. (AnkhSVN doesn't perform any work in this step, but VS needs to load it anyway to setup the menu and toolbar items)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and got it fixed when I uninstalled and reinstalled AnkhSVN.  Doing a repair wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only solution for me was to remove Registry keys explained in [Visual Studio 2012 Extension Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177800/visual-studio-2012-extension-issues).