# AnhkSVN not showing up in VS2012 Web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I just installed AnkhSvn-2.4.11610 with the intent of using it with VS2012 Express for Web but it's not showing up in the Plug-In Selection drop-down-box.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Visual Studio Express versions don't allow source code control plugins.

http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/Faq#head-5cfda3c01b2ff5bab6b3742c33ced4abe1426eb2

Comment: Ohhh... that explains it. Thanks :)

Comment: @podiluska: Is there any other source control tool which is compatible with Visual Studio Web Express?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari Not as far as I know - source control integration is not enabled in VS express.

Comment: @DharmikBhandari VS2012 Update 2 (Currently CTP) allows one to use Git and TFS from VS2012 Express.

Answer (score 33):

In VS2012 Go to `Tools -> Options... -> Source Control -> Plug-In Selection -> complement choice AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio`  (In the Current Source control plug-in Drop Down List Select this option) then it will work.