# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone SVN support?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, windows-8, windows-phone-8

Currently, I use the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone on my Windows 8 system. However, I can't find how to check out the SVN features, even if I install AnkshSVN. Does anybody have any solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AnhkSVN not showing up in VS2012 Web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509757/anhksvn-not-showing-up-in-vs2012-web)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express editions do not support plugins,  so AnhkSVN will not work.  You can use any SVN client you wish from outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you for your clean answers .